# WooCommerce (4.8.0) WordPress (5.6) not saving the SKU value for Variable Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, variable-product

I am afraid its a new issue.

Update the SKU value on main variable product is not shown, after successful update message.

While, update of each SKU value variation of this product succeeds.

I am using WooCommerce (4.8.0) WordPress (5.6)

Turned off all plugins, but Woocommerce  - did not help.

Replaced theme to default 2020 - did not help.

Debug is ON and clean on all tests & No JS issues reported.

Any idea what might be the issue? or how to debug it?

Comment: Note that StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support, so this is not the place for this kind of questions… Report this as a bug on WooCommerce support pages or on WooCommerce Github.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks. I saw similar questions, so I was hoping... Thanks for your note

Answer (score 0):

Does your variation have a ton of variations? If so it's possible that not all fields are saved due to too many form fields being submitted at once.

Also see: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/problems-with-large-amounts-of-data-not-saving-variations-rates-etc/#php-539-and-max_input_vars

You can edit your php.ini to allow more form-fields:

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```